# "git clone" yields hangup error even though I can telnet to port 9418

Tags: git

I tried to clone git://metaf2xml.git.sourceforge.net/ but this happened:

```
> git clone git://metaf2xml.git.sourceforge.net/ 
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/barry/METAF2XML/metaf2xml.git.sourceforge.net/.git/ 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I thought maybe the git port (9418 according to my /etc/services) was 
closed, but no:

```
> telnet metaf2xml.git.sourceforge.net git 
Trying 216.34.181.91... 
Connected to metaf2xml.git.sourceforge.net. 
Escape character is '^]'. 

QUIT
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to run other git commands first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because you are using the wrong url (do not go by what you see in web access). Try this:

```
git clone git://metaf2xml.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/metaf2xml/metaf2xml
```

http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=git&group_id=168043

Answer (score -1):

Check your ssh key in your ~/.ssh folder and the key that you uploaded to the host site.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

leave the password blank. Upload the id_rsa.pub to the site.

oops! missed the protocol. See manojlds' answer.

Comment: Adam, I think you're confusing sourceforge and github (github really does use ssh keys)

Comment: @barrycarter - Nothing to do with github or sourceforge, but the protocol. Github also has similar read-only git protocol urls.