# How to clone repositories from server port 9418?

Tags: git, clone, git-clone

I have a server with git running on port 9418.

Is it possible to list or clone all git repositories from that server?

It is supposed to be working, but for certain repo-name:

```
git clone git://ip/repo-name
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Git protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#_the_git_protocol) does not include listing repositories.

And it does not include authentication, which is why you won't find it in a corporate environment (where the port 9418 is closed off anyway)

Otherwise, provided your git daemon is running on the server, an URL like `git://<ip>:9418/repo` should work.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7801524/6309) (from 2011, unlikely to work in 2021):

```
git clone git://metaf2xml.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/metaf2xml/metaf2xml
```

2021:

```
git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/metaf2xml/code.git
```

Comment: The page https://sourceforge.net/p/metaf2xml/code/ci/master/tree/ lists the current working URL (switch from `HTTPS` to `git://`); `git ls-remote git://git.code.sf.net/p/metaf2xml/code.git` works.

Comment: @phd Thank you. I have updated the answer with the current `git://` URL. Always a surprise to see such an URL still valid nowadays.